# How to change the "Browse" button in Bootstrap custom file input?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to translate it to another language, any way to do that?

EDIT: Nevermind, figured it out myself.

```
.custom-file-label::after {
content: "Custom label" !important; }
```

or

use attribute data-browse="Your custom label"

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#translating-or-customizing-the-strings-with-html

Comment: could you please tell me clearly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

override on css:

```
.custom-file-input:lang(en)~.custom-file-label::after {
    content: "Browse";
}
```

change content

Answer (score -3):

The button isn't called the "browse button" — that's just the name your browser gives for it. Browsers are free to implement the file upload control however they like. In Safari, for example, it's called "Choose File" and it's on the opposite side of whatever you're probably using.

You can implement a custom look for the upload control using [the technique outlined on QuirksMode](https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html), but that goes beyond just changing the button's text.